# embedded resource vs content vs separate folder xml files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

I'm working witth .net visual studio and Nunit as unit testing tool.
Unit test data are retrieved from approximately 400 xml files.

Can you provide me the answer what is the best way to store the xml files from my 3 options:

1. xml as a embedded resourse
2. xml as a content
3. xmls are stored in a separate folder and not included in a solution

When working with second two scenarios I have found, that if you want to change xml, you need to close Nunit project because you have an error on saving xml file such as: file can't be modified, it is open in another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should use separate test data files in a folder that is included into the test project. It offers you a flexible way to change your test data or add/remove them.

When you include the folder in you project, it is automaticly part of the checkin/checkout and is never missed.

Comment: Hi C Sharper. I think this is 1 and 2 variants? Which on of them is better?

Comment: No, variant 3. but the folder is inculed into the project.